# Docusign webhook listener with Authorization headers

Tags: docusignapi

Hi I have created webhook listener for docusign and its working fine I am able to listen events.Now I have implemented Authorization for my listener and it accept token from Authorization header.So my question is how I can configure DocuSign to add headers in web hook request.My listener expect below headers in request.

```
Authorization:Bearer {{default_token}}
Content-Type:application/json
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to set custom headers through the DocuSign Connect module, as of today. The closest you can get to that is to include an X509 Certificate in the SOAP header, which is optional.

See the DocuSign Connect (PDF) doc through the Dev Center -> Documentation page for more info.

or you can visit the below blog for Securing Your Connect Webhook Listener-

https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-securing-connect-webhook-listener/